# How can you fade out and in between two images?

Tags: android, transition, splash-screen

I have two images loading in my splash screen. The first image opens (starting the splash screen) then the second image opens. Once the second image fades out the MainActivity starts. Now my question is how do I make my first image fade out, then fade in with my second image?

I'm not trying to cross fade between the two either.  I'm trying to do a complete fade out then fade in transition.

The splash.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/lin_lay"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinning_wheel_image"
        android:background="@drawable/splashscreen1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The mainanim.xml

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/splashscreen1" android:duration="2500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/splashscreen2" android:duration="4000" />
</animation-list>
```

The Splash.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splashsound);
    ourSong.start();
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(10500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.theapplication.app.STARTINGPOINT");
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);

            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

@Override
public void setRequestedOrientation(int requestedOrientation) {
    super.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    ImageView mainimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.spinning_wheel_image);
    mainimage.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.mainamin);
    mainanimation = (AnimationDrawable) mainimage.getBackground();
    mainanimation.start();
}
```

Comment: what is problem here?can you provide log cat.

Comment: Hey Harshid thanks for your comment. My problem is I'm trying to make the two images in my splash screen fade out and in. Because right now my splash screen show one image, (no fade) then the other. I want to show a fade transition.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [demo.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113831/An-Advanced-Splash-Screen-for-Android-App)

may be helpful for you.

Comment: Ok checking it out now I will let you know my results.

Comment: Hey Harshid, still having difficulty with the problem. I also tried the link in your comment for about 30 min. Is it possible for you to implement the fade into the codes I gave above?

Comment: link is helpful for me so i share.you have to implement in your way.